# backbone populate collection from external json

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Below is the current code structure I have in place for a collection that I have manually constructed. I have a json file on my server which I am now trying to load in and basically remove the manual one and construct a collection based on that data. Was wondering what would I possibly need to change below to my code to help accommodate this.

```
        var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
                name: 'John Doe',
                age: 30,
                occupation: 'worker'
            }
        });


        var GameCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Game,
            url: 'path/to/json',

            parse: function(response) {
                return response;
            }
        });

        var GamesView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'ul',

            render: function() {
                //filter through all items in a collection
                this.collection.each(function(game){
                    var gameView = new GameView({model: game});
                    this.$el.append(gameView.render().el);
                }, this)

                return this;
            }
        });

        var GameView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'li',

            template: _.template($('#gameTemplate').html()),

            render: function() {
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
        });

        var gameCollection = new GameCollection([
            {
                name: 'John Doe',
                age: 30,
                occupation: 'worker'
            }, 
            {
                name: 'John Doe',
                age: 30,
                occupation: 'worker'
            }, 
            {
                name: 'John Doe',
                age: 30,
                occupation: 'worker'
            }
        ]);

        var gamesView = new GamesView({collection: gameCollection});

        $(document.body).append(gamesView.render().el);
```

Comment: So you're currently saying `new GameCollection(some_big_array_of_stuff)` but now you want to load the collection from the server?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to not use the manual array of objects I created for testing but I now want to try to load in a json object I have on the server and try to parse that data. Not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of the many things to love about Backbone. I don't know what you are using for your backend, but you state that you have a json file on your server, hopefully a json file full of the models that should be in your collection. And now here is the magic code (drumroll please..):

```
var GameCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Game,
  url: 'path/to/json/on/external/server',
});

var gameCollection = new GameCollection();
gameCollection.fetch();
```

Not much to it, right?  Of course there are several options you can add or change to a `fetch`, so check out the docs here: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch. Backbone uses `jQuery.ajax()` be default, so check out the docs here to see all of the options: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You shouldn't need the custom parse in your collection unless your models on the server don't match your backbone models.

**Things to know**:
`fetch` is asynchronous. It takes time to talk to the server, and the rest of your javascript will move on and complete. You will probably need to at least add a callback function to the `success` option, which will be called when `fetch` is finished, and it is good to add something to `error` as well, in case something goes wrong. You can add data as a query string so that your backend can use it using the `data` option, the data has to be an object. Here is an example:

```
gameCollection.fetch({
  data: {collection_id: 25},
  success: function(){
    renderCollection(); // some callback to do stuff with the collection you made
  },
  error: function(){
    alert("Oh noes! Something went wrong!")
  }
});
```

`fetch` should receive data as JSON, so your url should either exclusive return JSON or be set up to detect an AJAX request and respond to it with JSON.

Comment: Right. But the tricky part for a (possible) beginner is that `fetch` is an AJAX call and you need to attach `render` to some events (say `'reset'` or something hidden behind a `success` callback).

Comment: That ought to do it. If OP has listeners set up for a change in the collection that would make it work without a callback, but I think a callback will be required in most situations.

Comment: So I was able to update my current code above to what you have mentioned. It returns a "success" alert so thats a good sign. I also posted my server json file, as the structure is different from the other one I was working with before. I guess the next step for me is to be able to utilize the #gameTemplate I've created and start seeing the data appended to the html using underscore.

Comment: @Anks, glad to help. The success function will also provide the following arguments for your function, in this order: data, textStatus, jqXHR. So if you run into trouble add these arguments to your function and see what they are. I recommend that you revert your question to its original form, this site is designed to be a reference to others who might have the same issue months or years from now. I think you explained your problem well originally, if you revert your question back to the way it was people can see the relevant question and the answers that match that question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to fetch it from server as RustyToms said. And the other consideration is how to force the collection view to render itself again once data collected from server, as muistooshort commented.

If you manipulating `fetch` or `sync` you'll need to do it multiple times when there are more than one collection in app.

Doing such is native with Marionette, but in plain Backbone you can mimic the method of Marionette's CollectionView and do such:

```
//For the collection view
var GamesView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function({
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render, this);
  });
  // Others
});
```

Then, when collection data fetched from server, the collection will trigger a `reset` event, the collection view noticed this event and render itself again.

For more than one collections, you can extract the code into a parent object in app and inherit from that.

```
var App.CollectionView = Backbone.View.extent({
  initialize: //code as above
});

var GamesView = App.CollectionView.extend({
  //Your code without initialize
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old at this point, but wanted to answer for anyone else stuck on this.

The code seems to come from the tutorial found here: http://codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/a-complete-guide-for-learning-backbone-js/

I too re-purposed the demo app found in that tutorial and had trouble rendering using external data.

**The first thing** is that the data itself needs to be converted to valid JSON or else you'll get a `.parse()` error.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 3 column 9 of the JSON data
```

or

```
error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token n
```

In your data source file, object properties need to be surrounded by quotes. It should look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 30,
    "occupation": "worker"
  },
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 30,
    "occupation": "worker"
  },
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 30,
    "occupation": "worker"
  }
]
```

**Secondly**, once it's clear the external data is loading, we need to get it to render. I solved this (perhaps ungracefully) by moving the `render()` command into the success function of your `gameCollection.fetch()`.

```
gameCollection.fetch({
  success: function(collection, response, options) {
    console.log('Success!! Yay!!');
    $(document.body).append(gamesView.render().el);
  },
  error: function(collection, response, options) {
    console.log('Oh, no!');
    // Display some errors that might be useful
    console.error('gameCollection.fetch error: ', options.errorThrown);
  }
});
```

There are certainly better ways to accomplish this, but this method directly converts the *code learned in the tutorial* into something that works with external data.